# How do you animate while fetching data with redux and thunk?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

Say I have a index page like Facebook with a list of friends. Say I want to pre-fetch your first ten friends' profiles, so that when you route to one of those profiles, the application won't need to make a request.

But say I want to animate a transition for .x seconds to the profile page so that, in case the profile isn't loaded, you don't see a loading screen (hoping that the actual request would return in less than the animation time).

The tricky part for me to wrap my head around is: when do I change the route and re-render the page with the actual profile (rather than the animation transitioning to it).

It seems set in stone that the router should be concerned only with fetching the data necessary, waiting, and then finally rendering the actual profile.

It seems then that the action creator must figure out when to change the route. And since it seems the route can only be changed after **BOTH** the transition **AND** the API call have finished, the only way I can figure to do it is with an action creator that looks something like:

```
    function visit_profile(profile_id) {
      return (dispatch) => {
        download_promise = dispatch(download_profile(profile_id));
        animation_promise = dispatch(transition_to_profile(profile_id));
        return Promise.all([download_promise, animation_promise]).then(
          (profile) => dispatch(view_profile(profile_id)),
          (error) => dispatch(404_profile())
        );
      };
    }

    // Downloads a profile and puts it into store.
    function download_profile() { ... }

    // Kicks off the animations (with a promise that is resolved when the animation is finished).
    function transition_to_profile() { ... }

    // Changes the URL, thereby re-rendering the page with the actual profile.
    function view_profile() { ... }
```

But this seems overly complicated to me. Whenever I'm doing something right in redux, I know, because it just feels right. This doesn't. It seems like something is really wrong. But I can't see any other way to do it. But, after looking through a lot of examples, I'm just not finding anything that puts me on the right path.

Are there any established conventions for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found an answer?